# Laggy response from Stack Overflow in certain situations

Tags: bug, status-norepro

This happens when multiple new actions shows up as flagged in the upper left hand corner (The red raindrop with a number). It will only happen with 3 or more. If you click the number to show the dialog, then click off on the page somewhere (not a link, or a link if you want), the dialog will go away and so will the red raindrop. However, page requests will become rather laggy for some time period. I am not sure how it evens back out - perhaps by re-visiting the inbox area. Eventually it does, but it gets very laggy when in that state.

Comment: We see you're using Chrome on two computers; are you seeing this on your XP box or your Windows 7 box?

Comment: I can't repro this in Chrome on either Windows or OS X.

Comment: @JarrodDixon - It occurs on both. I could be mistaken about how the lag is caused, but I do notice it. Usually like I said when there are numerous items in the inbox. In addition, I believe I am usually trying to refresh the page by clicking on the title when more than 3 of the items enter the inbox. Perhaps too many requests on my end could be causing the lag. The lag only lasts for a little bit and it rarely occurs.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - I will try to examine it more the next time it happens to get a better scenario for reproducing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue on the current build of our sites. If the problem remains please let me know.

Comment: I have not seen this behavior for a very long time. Thank you for reviewing it though.